# How to solve this Baby Bleichenbacher Attack?

Tags: rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

I am trying to solve this problem from https://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf.
I am having trouble with this question :

(Baby Bleichenbacher attack). Consider an RSA public key (n, e), where n is an RSA
modulus, and e is an encryption exponent. For x ∈ Zn, consider the predicate Px : Zn → {0, 1}
defined as:

[image]

Show that by querying the predicate Px at about log2 n points, it is possible to learn the
value of x.

Comment: Hint: assume $x<n/2$. What do you learn when submitting $r=2$?

Comment: @fgrieu Assuming x < n/2, if x \in [0, n/4] then P_x(r) will return 0, else it will return 1. I am getting that we are reducing range for possible values of x (we can use something like binary search), but how do we actually learn value of x?

Answer (score 1):

By definition the starting knowledge is that *x* is in (0, n) interval. Then you test each power of 2 (incl. zero) as *r*. Each test tells you the new boundary for the interval to which *x* belong. If *y* eq. 1 -- we should drop lower half of the current interval, if it's eq. 0 then we drop upper bound. Let's imagine that for $2^0$ it returns 1, so we know that *x* is in ($n/2$, n). For the next step ($2^1$) if it returns 0, then *x* is in ($n/2$, $3n/4$). And so on.

As $P_x(0)$ tells us **half** of {Z_n} where *x* belongs, doubling of *x* let us iteratively calculate the interval (with length 1 in the end of the process) to which *x* will be wrapping around after each doubling.

PS Never heard term "Baby Bleichenbacher", but it doesn't differs in essence from "RSA parity oracle", which is easy to get a lot of examples, descriptions and discussions around.